# Firefox shows duplicate window options after installing Unite gnome extension on ubnutu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, firefox, gnome-shell-extension

I really liked how we used to have the window action icons on the top bar back in ubuntu 16.04. Now to get the similar top bar feel on Ubuntu 20.04, I installed [Unite Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/). This used to give me almost the same look and feel but for some reason it is not working properly on Firefox 90.0.2 and is showing the window options separate to the top bar (refer to the image below).

Could anyone help me on this and how I can resolve this? Or is there any other extensions better than **Unite** to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

right click title bar -> choose appearance -> on the bottom bar enable title bar (checkbox)